# An error occurred requesting a personal access token. Cannot read property x-vss-resourceenant of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm using VSCode (version 1.23.1) and connected to visual studio team services (VSTS) using the VS [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team). I was able to connect to VSTS repository and source control the files just fine. After recently upgrading to this new version of VSCode i'm unable to team sign in and getting the following error

`(team) An error occurred requesting a personal access token for https://mysitename.visualstudio.com. (Cannot read property 'x-vss-resourcetenant' of undefined)`

I've also tried manually entering PAT token and get the "connect ECONNREFUSED" error in the status bar with Team exclamation mark

Screenshots below

[image]
[image][image]

UserSettings VSCode

```
{
"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe",
"tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
"team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
"team.logging.level": "debug",
"tfvc.proxy": "http://corporate.proxy.server:8080/proxy"
}
```

[Team extension log file.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/files/2062109/team-extension.log)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the repo when you connect VSTS in VScode, Git repo or TFVC repo? Can you share the screen shot of the VS code when the error occur?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT its connecting to TFVC repo. And I have added the screenshots.

Comment: What if you try signin with VSTS by use the command >team sigin (https://ibb.co/bTn0Fy) instead of clicking Team button (https://ibb.co/hYXNTJ)?

Comment: Team button, click, does not do anything (does not open any login dialog window or command pallette). I m trying using the team sigin command only( by going to View menu > Command Pallette> Team: Signin) .

Comment: What's the version of  VSTS extension in VS code did you installed? Or What if you uninstall and re-install the extension in VS code?

Comment: Yes I have tried reinstalling the extension several times with no luck. I have reinstalled VS Code and getting a different error from extension now. Attaching the screenshot

Comment: Have you configured tf.exe to user settings in VS code (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#configure-tfvc-support) after reinstalled VS code?

Comment: The new error is gone after updating the tfvc.location. But I'm back to the original error again regarding error in requesting the PAT token. Seems like an security issue. I m behind a corporate firewall. I have tried adding the tfvc.proxy setting in the user settings like `"tfvc.proxy": "http://corporate.proxy.server:8080/proxy"` but still getting the same error. Going to attach the team-extension log the question.

Comment: And please also make sure the path for tfvc.location is using `\\\` instead of `\\` (like `"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe"`).

Comment: Sure. will do that and I have added the link to the log file in the question above.

Comment: Updated the single backslash with double backslash but still no luck with the error.

Comment: Can you show the screen shot for how the settings file is configured? And based on the second screen shot you shared, you were not open a TFVC workspace since there has not `$tf` folder shows under `PPED.CLIENT` folder.

Comment: I have added the user settings in the question. Using VS 2017 command prompt, I navigate to the application folder. Type `tf workspace` command.  It opens `Edit Workspace` dialogue. I click on Source control folder of my project and it opens the collection on TFS `https://corporatedomain.visualstudio.com/` and I can navigate to the source folder just fine.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I have accessed the repository from an external network and did not get any error. So it definitely is a permissions issue on this network. Is this `"tfvc.proxy": "http://corporate.proxy.server:8080/proxy"` the right syntax for adding the proxy server in the usersettings.json file?

Comment: You can refer this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/247.

Comment: As advised on that link, I've added the http_proxy in windows environment variable and I'm able to finally connect.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, I added it as a solution. You can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you connect to VSTS with proxy setting, you can add `http.proxy` and it's value into environment variable.

More details, you can refer the similar issue [Unable to signin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/247).

Comment: http.proxy settings did not work in the user settings. I have added http_proxy value in the environment variables section.
Steps: (windows+R) -> type "rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables" and hit enter-> add http_proxy

Answer (score 1):

A tip for those like me with corporate proxy issues:

- when setting proxy in environment variables make sure you do so through advanced system setting (which requires admin user/pass) so that you can add the proxy as a system variable not a user variable
- on VSTS set your token to all scopes
- open VS code as admin before you enter the `team:signin` command